# Javascript Alert function in opened page doesn't appear on first load

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-mobile, cordova

Okay, what I'm trying to do is,  make a looping of data in ajax and show it in a list view and allow it to be clicked.. Every data linking to another page and contain an id..
Right after I clicked, it will directing me to a new HTML page with the URL that has an id on it..

e.g : htmlName.html?id=1

Here is my code :

```
//(first html)
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.css" />  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>  
<script>  
$(document).ready(function()
{  
var output = $('#output4');  
$.ajax({  
    url: 'http://localhost/test1.php',  
    type: "GET",   
    dataType: 'jsonp',  
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback',  
    timeout: 5000,  
    success: function(data, status){        
        $.each(data, function(i,item){  
            var email = "<li><a href=\"app2.html?id="+item.lo+"\" data-transition=\"slide\"><h1>"+item.email+"</h1><img src="+item.comment+" /><p>"+item.email+"</p></a></li>";         
            output.append(email);
            output.listview("refresh");});  
    },  
    error: function(){  
        output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
    }});  
});  
</script>
```

The opened page has an Javascript Alert(id). The id which I Get from the url(sent from the previous page)..
But what my problem is, the Alert doesn't appear when I load the page, BUT it will appear after I RE-LOAD the page..

Here's the code :

```
//second html
<script>  
//function to get id from the URL
var params = {};  
if (location.search) {
var parts = location.search.substring(1).split('&');

for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    var nv = parts[i].split('=');
    if (!nv[0]) continue;
    params[nv[0]] = nv[1] || true;
    }
}    
var forIDalert = params.id;  
alert(forIDalert);  
</script>
```

Anyway I'm wondering, when I delete the script :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

The Alert function run as it is supposed to be(on first load or without to reload the page), but I need that script, because I'm working on a jquery mobile and phonegap..
So, anyone know how to make the alert appear just after I clicked the link on the first HTML without need to RELOAD the page?
And, sorry for my bad English..
Thanks, Regards.

Comment: Try this `$(document).on('pagebeforeshow, '[data-role=page]', function () { alert(this.id); });` another note, don't use `.ready()` in JQM.

Comment: Thanks Omar, but sorry I still can't get the alert on the first load.
Any other suggestion?